# How to make a Taser?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, dc-transformer

I am new. I'm from grade 6,so I am pretty much a noob,but I want to make a taser with an output of 10 to 20 kv dc. The power supply is maybe 9 volt batteries or 6 volt batteries but not car battery because I want to make in portable and not heavy. Could anyone please tell me where could I buy the DC to DC converter (since the power source is DC,but the output does'nt have to be DC) or maybe tell me where to buy high power DC transformer (I know transformer does'nt work on DC but there is a DC transformer,go to http://www.custompowertransformer.com/Difference-between-AC-and-DC-Electric-transformers.html for more information about DC transformer). Thank you.

Comment: To quote from your link "Since then, electrical engineers have developed DC transformers, primarily using special circuitry". I want one of those DC transformers! But that aside: Buy an electric gas lighter, and try it on your own body. Don't come here for advice on making a weapon.

Comment: vote to close: Asks for a plan to build a potentially dangerous weapon.

Comment: You'll shoot  your eye out kid.

Comment: What is a DC transformer? And the information in the link looks incorrect... "In the search to create electrical energy, scientists discovered that electrical and magnetic fields are related. A magnetic field near a wire causes electrons to flow in a single direction along the wire because they are repelled and attracted by the north or south poles. Thus, DC power from a battery was born" .... looks like stuff written by a marketing person who needs a lesson on physics to me...

Answer (score 2):

A fixed oscillator would not be efficient enough and will drain the batteries quickly, you need a capacitive discharge circuit similar to the ones used in photo flashes.  See this link http://www.sentex.ca/~mec1995/circ/hv/stungun/stungun.html

Please be safe, HV projects are only advisable for experienced DIYers.

Answer (score 1):

Tazers are actually running on AC at the output, that's why there's a clicking sound when they are discharging.

You are better off building a little oscillator (either discrete with a few transistors or with a 555 timer) that runs on DC and drives a step up transformer connected in reverse.  A typical audio or signal transformer will work ok from [mouser](http://www.mouser.com/Passive-Components/Transformers-Audio-Signal/_/N-5gbg).  Then you can either use some diode/capacitor voltage doublers to step it up, or use an additional output transformer to get even higher voltages.  You can find some ideas [here](http://www3.telus.net/chemelec/Projects/Stun-Gun/Stun-Gun.htm).

Don't hurt yourself....